# I want to rebuild ssh keys for my git, should I just directly remove old ssh keys file?

Tags: git

I want rebuild ssh keys for my git. So I should just directly remove `.ssh` directory and then build ssh keys right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes if you want or else you can also add more ssh keys without removing .ssh folder. You just have to give custom names to the **id_rsa keys** generated.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Check the [reference](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/). After generating you can add the id_rsa.pub keys to your github account.